# Can I dynamically create a List by scanning the beans in a spring configuration file?

Tags: java, spring

For example, I have created a slew of 'test-my-service' Objects in my Spring config and each Object has data that concerns a contrived test scenario. Currently I am manually editing the Spring config every time I want to run a new scenario, or a List of scenarios. Is there a way I could add a prefix to a bean name, and then load all of the beans with that prefix (or suffix) into a List or Array? Something like....

```
<bean name="env1-test1"/>
<bean name="env2-test1"/>
```

This is the code that I ended up writing. I wasn't able to get the beanFactory Object initialized from the example that I accepted earlier:

```
String[] beanNames = context.getBeanNamesForType(Inputs.class); 
for (String beanName : beanNames) { 
     if (beanName.startsWith("env")) { 
          System.out.println("Found a bean of type " + Inputs.class.getName()); 
          Inputs bean = (Inputs)context.getBean(beanName); 
          doTest(bean); 
     }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `ListableBeanFactory` interface to retrieve all bean names, and then load the ones you're interested in:

```
private @Autowired ListableBeanFactory beanFactory;

public void doStuff() {
   for (String beanName : beanFactory.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
      if (beanName.startsWith("env")) { // or whatever check you want to do
         Object bean = beanFactory.getBean(beanName)
         // .. do something with it
      }
   }
}
```

Alternatively, if the target beans are all of the same type, then you can ask for them all by type, instead of by name, using `ListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType()` or `ListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType()`.

The injected `ListableBeanFactory` will be the "current" application context.

Answer (score 2):

I've never tried before, but looks like you can get a list of all beans from the context:  http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory.html#getBeanDefinitionNames%28%29

From that it wouldn't be hard to filter on the names and load the matches.