# Finding stateful singleton beans

Tags: java, spring, singleton, state

Today, we found this pattern in our code:

```
class Foo {
    private List<String> errors;

    public void addError(String error) { ... }
    public List<String> getErrors();
}
```

While the code seems to work, this is a singleton Spring bean and it's injected in several independent places and the consumers of the bean assume that they each have their own list of errors. So this introduces subtle bugs.

The obvious solution is to educate developers to avoid this kind of error but I was wondering if there is a static or runtime code analysis tool which can find this kind of bug.

For example, a bean postprocessor could analyze the bean before it's returned and look for private fields that aren't `@Autowired`.

Comment: Can we use @postConstruct to reset that private field ?

Comment: @SREEPRASADGOVINDANKUTTY: You could try but it wouldn't work since `@PostConstruct` would be called only once when creating Foo. You can't use `@PostConstruct` in bean A to reset the field since that would clear the list for bean B as well.

Comment: Though not a very clean way, you can try spring APO, add afterAdvice and in that method you can check these fields.

Comment: if we use prototype instead of singleton scope then new Foo() is created every time an object is required and wont each developer get their own list of errors ?

Comment: @SREEPRASADGOVINDANKUTTY: Turning `Foo` into a prototype is a workaround but it doesn't solve the bug. I would like to have a unit test which tells developers when they make this kind of mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After pouring some more brains (ours and other peoples) on this, we came up with this approach:

1. Install a `BeanPostProcessor` which makes sure that all singleton beans (i.e. where the scope in the bean definition is `Singleton`) have the custom annotation `@Stateless` on the actual bean type.

   We chose a custom annotation instead of reusing `@Singleton` since we need this functionality elsewhere, too.

   If the annotation is missing, the factory throws an error.
2. In a unit test, we use `ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider` with out custom annotation to locate all classes on the classpath. We can then do the complex and expensive tests to make sure the bean has no state that changes after the initial configuration (i.e. after the autowiring has happened).

The second step could become a little bit easier if we moved the autowired fields into the constructor but we don't like methods that take many, many arguments. It would be nice if Java or an IDE could generate builders from the bean code. Since that's not the case, we stick to autowired fields and/or setters.

Comment: Is there a generic way to figure out if a bean is stateless ? How did you write the expensive tests ? Is that specific to implementation ?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a JUnit test that would load your app config.
This could combine ListableBeanFactory from here :

[Can I dynamically create a List by scanning the beans in a spring configuration file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808048/can-i-dynamically-create-a-list-by-scanning-the-beans-in-a-spring-configuration)

with the 'isSingleton' check here :

[How to enforce a prototype scope of Spring beans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538953/how-to-enforce-a-prototype-scope-of-spring-beans)

i.e. list all the beans in the app context, then check to see which are singletons.

This would let you find all singleton beans...although it wouldn't really prevent your error case where someone treats one of these singletons as if it were not.